# RStudio through SecureCRT

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to setup RStudio so that it uses a remote R session (console) that I am connected to through secureCRT. Is there a way to tunnel commands so that they are sent directly from RStudio to that remote session?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to do this, but if your goal is to have an R session running somewhere remotely that you can connect to from anywhere, this is indeed possible using RStudio.

Set up the [RStudio Server](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/server/getting_started)--it will start a web server that serves the RStudio IDE as a web app. From there, you can connect to your R session (and IDE session) from any web browser.